# Fail safe variable length variable assignment

Tags: python

The Idea is to assign variable based on length of the values.

I tried something like this.

```
values_tuple = ((1, 2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1,), ())
for var1, var2, var3 in values_tuple:
    print('var1', var1, 'var2', var2, 'var3', var3)
```

This obviously fails

This is current working code.

```
values_tuple = ((1, 2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1,), ())
for values in values_tuple:
    if values:
        var1 = var2 = var3 = None
        var1 = values[0]
        if len(values) > 2:
            var3 = values[2]
        elif len(values) > 1:
            var2 = values[1]
        print('var1', var1, 'var2', var2, 'var3', var3)
```

Is there any short way of doing this?
Above example is for simple explanation.

The detailed explanation could be like this.

Input

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                sr.
            </th>
            <th>
                File date<br>
                Approved date<br>
                Launch date
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1.
            </td>
            <td>
                1/1/2020<br>
                1/2/2020<br>
                1/3/2020
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                2.
            </td>
            <td>
                1/1/2021<br>
                1/2/2021
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                3.
            </td>
            <td>
                TBD
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Output:

```
[
    {'file': '1/1/2020', 'approval': '1/2/2020', 'launch': '1/3/2020'},
    {'file': '1/1/2021', 'approval': '1/2/2021', 'launch': ''},
    {'file': 'TBD', 'approval': '', 'launch': ''},
]
```

Comment: `var1, var2, var3 = values + (None,) * (3 - len(values))`…? But is it necessary to unpack those tuples at all…?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is necessary to unpack those tuples. This is just sample. Actual code uses html table and based on values present assign them keys and finally convert to json

Comment: Are you looking for `print(*(" ".join(f"var{i} {n}" for i, n in enumerate(x, 1)) for x in values_tuple), sep="\n")`

Comment: @deceze Thanks. This works. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: @Sayse. Nope. I need them as variables. Or as dictionary.

Comment: You should create an [mcve] about the actual issue you're trying to solve, I don't see any reason to unpack the tuples into seperate variables

Comment: Thanks. Right. Just starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pad a tuple to the expected length with `t + (None,) * (n - len(t))`, where `n` is the required length. E.g.:

```
>>> t = (1, 2)
>>> t + (None,) * (3 - len(t))
(1, 2, None)
>>> t = (1,)
>>> t + (None,) * (3 - len(t))
(1, None, None)
```

So:

```
values_tuple = ((1, 2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1,), ())

for var1, var2, var3 in (t + (None,) * (3 - len(t)) for t in values_tuple):
    print('var1', var1, 'var2', var2, 'var3', var3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just enumerate over the `values_tuple` and use that to create the variable name, no need to create seperate variables

```
print(*(" ".join(f"var{i} {n}" for i, n in enumerate(x, 1)) for x in values_tuple), sep="\n")
```

It might be more readable to not use nested compehensions here though

```
for x in values_tuple:
    print(*(" ".join(f"var{i} {n}" for i, n in enumerate(x, 1)))
```

Comment: can we convert this to dict like `[{'var1': 1, 'var2': 2}, {'var1':...}]`

Comment: @RahulPatel - `[{f"var{i}": n for i, n in enumerate(x, 1)} for x in values_tuple]`

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for help. This is final code that I arrived at.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for row in soup.select('table tbody tr'):
    keys = ['file', 'approve', 'launch']
    values = row.select('td')[1].stripped_strings
    print({k: v for k, v in zip(, values)})
```

Answer (score -1):

alternative answer using itertools:

```
import itertools
values_tuple = ((1, 2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1,), ())
for var1,var2,var3 in zip(*itertools.zip_longest(*values_tuple)):
    print('var1', var1, 'var2', var2, 'var3', var3)
```

Comment: That fails if none of the tuples has 3 items…

Comment: Then why are you using var1 to var3 in the first place?

Comment: @deceze: You are right. In my case it may happen that none of the row has 3 items.